# R ggplot of three survival curves, next to each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

im trying to make three survival curves fit next to each other

here is the code

```
library(readxl)
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)
library(gridExtra)

createSurvivalPlot <- function(file_path) {
# Read the spreadsheet
data <- read_excel(file_path)

# Select required columns
data_selected <- data[, c("patient_ids", "pfs_days_from_test_day", "pfs_event", "VAL1_is_normal", "VAL2_is_normal")]

# Modify VAL1_is_normal
data_selected$VAL1_is_normal <- ifelse(data_selected$VAL1_is_normal == 1, "NOR", "ABN")

# Modify VAL2_is_normal
data_selected$VAL2_is_normal <- ifelse(data_selected$VAL2_is_normal == 1, "NOR", "ABN")

# Create a survival object
sfit <- Surv(data_selected$pfs_days_from_test_day, data_selected$pfs_event)

fit <- survfit(sfit ~ interaction(data_selected$VAL2_is_normal, data_selected$VAL1_is_normal, sep="_"), data = data_selected)

# Plot using ggsurvplot from survminer
plot_obj <- ggsurvplot(fit, data=data_selected,
                       title=paste("Survival Curve based on val1 and val2"),
                       xlab="Days from Test Day",
                       risk.table=TRUE,   # Display risk table
                       pval=FALSE,        # Remove p-value
                       conf.int=FALSE,    # Remove confidence intervals
                       legend.title="VAL1 & VAL2 Status",
                       legend.labs=c("ABN_ABN" = "1-Abnormal & 2-Abnormal", 
                                     "NOR_ABN" = "1-Normal & 2-Abnormal", 
                                     "ABN_NOR" = "1-Abnormal & 2-Normal", 
                                     "NOR_NOR" = "1-Normal & 2-Normal")
)

return(plot_obj)
}

files <- c("pre_treatment.xlsx", 
       "early_treatment.xlsx", 
       "later_treatment.xlsx")

plot_objects <- c(
createSurvivalPlot(files[1]), 
createSurvivalPlot(files[2]), 
createSurvivalPlot(files[3])
)

# Start the PDF device driver
pdf("Survival_Curve_based_on_val1_and_val2.pdf", width=21, height=10)

# Use do.call with grid.arrange to arrange multiple plots 
plots_list <- lapply(plot_objects, function(obj) list(obj$plot, obj$table))
combined_plots <- do.call(grid.arrange, c(plots_list, list(ncol=3)))

# Close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

And I keep getting this error

`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'sfit' not found`

and even if I write out the function call and repeat the code three times, I get

`no applicable method for 'ggplot_build' applied to an object of class "environment"`

to me it's weird already that the error you get in the function is different than the error you get out of the function

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The object `sfit` is not created - what happens when you just run the line `sfit <- Surv(data_selected$pfs_days_from_test_day, data_selected$pfs_event)`?

Comment: it creates the sfit object. That is in the environment, I can see it. But the ggplot call doesn't.